# Why can't I make a duplicate of my visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS 2012 and when I make a copy of the solution in a different folder and start modifying the code , the files in the original project folder also change.

I am curious as to how are there two projects still linked.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time without any problems.  I would open the project and solution files in a text editor and check for absolute paths.  Normally those files use relative paths which allows copying the files like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just copying the solution file or the entire contents of the solution (i.e., all the files and projects in that solution)? A solution file is just a logical grouping of other projects. So if you are just copying the solution file itself, it would still reference the original files.